# Detecting Relevant Part of Video in Python

Tags: python, video, analysis

I have a whole series of MP4 videos, and most of them are irrelevant to our interest, however there are some 1 to 2 minute sections that we want to trim out.

Problem is the relevance can either be picked from slides, showing what the next sections shows, or from the audio description.

Can anyone suggest a method preferably in python, to analysis the video, pick the relevant section of the video, even though the phrase I'm looking for might not be an exact match?

My current think is to transcribe the video, insert any slides into the transcript, then use AI to find the relevant sections. However before I start on this journey, I wondered if anyone knew of any opensource python libraries etc. That would fit the bill, it seems like something that might have been tackled before.